# Javascript merged array sort with date values giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, object

First of all i'm sorry if this is question is not relevant. I'm not familiar with ecma & javascript.
I have 2 objects.

I want to merge them and sort with date field. Merging perfectly with `.push()` But when i'm trying to sort it with `add_date` value, i'm getting unexpected results.

First Object:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PKXLF1",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-01-07 01:35:25",
        "value": 448.4
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PTO3U8",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-06-25 20:39:44",
        "value": 472
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PTYE1M",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-07-01 09:56:10",
        "value": 1320.77
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PXF079",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-09-06 16:57:09",
        "value": 1859.68
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PZ62E5",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-10-10 18:13:17",
        "value": 755.2
    }
]
```

And Second Object;

```
[
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-01-22 01:35:25",
        "value": 448.4
    },
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-08-02 20:24:57",
        "value": 1000
    },
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-10-04 14:48:55",
        "value": 792
    }
]
```

What i've tried so far;

[How to sort an array by a date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property)

This question's accepted answer

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

I've tried but it giving unexpected result like;

```
0: {type: "Sipariş - # PKXLF1", note: "", add_date: "2019-01-07 01:35:25", value: 448.4}
1: {type: "Sipariş - # PTO3U8", note: "", add_date: "2019-06-25 20:39:44", value: 472}
2: {type: "Sipariş - # PTYE1M", note: "", add_date: "2019-07-01 09:56:10", value: 1320.77}
3: {type: "Sipariş - # PXF079", note: "", add_date: "2019-09-06 16:57:09", value: 1859.68}
4: {type: "Tahsilat - Havale / Eft", note: "Ziraat Bankası Gelen Havale/EFT", add_date: "2019-01-22 01:35:25", value: 448.4}
5: {type: "Tahsilat - Havale / Eft", note: "Ziraat Bankası Gelen Havale/EFT", add_date: "2019-08-02 20:24:57", value: 1000}
```

What am i missing? Does my `add_date` field has `wrong date values`?

Any help greatly appricated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you name you merged array array? And the sort method you paste there's a property called date. Your object has the property "add_date". Change the array sort method to something like this:

```js
const a = [
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PKXLF1",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-01-07 01:35:25",
        "value": 448.4
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PTO3U8",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-06-25 20:39:44",
        "value": 472
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PTYE1M",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-07-01 09:56:10",
        "value": 1320.77
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PXF079",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-09-06 16:57:09",
        "value": 1859.68
    },
    {
        "type": "Sipari\u015f - # PZ62E5",
        "note": "",
        "add_date": "2019-10-10 18:13:17",
        "value": 755.2
    }
];

const b = [
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-01-22 01:35:25",
        "value": 448.4
    },
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-08-02 20:24:57",
        "value": 1000
    },
    {
        "type": "Tahsilat - Havale \/ Eft",
        "note": "Ziraat Bankas\u0131 Gelen Havale\/EFT",
        "add_date": "2019-10-04 14:48:55",
        "value": 792
    }
];
const c = [...a, ...b];


c.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(a.add_date) - new Date(b.add_date);
});

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. That's what i've done, but it's not working.

Comment: If you run the code above, the array will be sorted by start date. Isn't that the expected result?

Comment: Actually i got the answer. That's not about sorting. Thanks for effort.

Comment: `new Date(a.add_date)` returns an invalid Date in at least one commonly used browser. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) "2019-10-04 14:48:55" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. The format of the OP dates will sort correctly without parsing to Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

The date strings in the objects are in a format that can be sorted lexically, there's no need to convert them to Dates.

You can merge simply using the spread syntax `...` and sort using `<` and `>`, e.g.

```js
let arrA = [
    {"add_date": "2019-01-07 01:35:25"},
    {"add_date": "2019-06-25 20:39:44"},
    {"add_date": "2019-07-01 09:56:10"},
    {"add_date": "2019-09-06 16:57:09"},
    {"add_date": "2019-10-10 18:13:17"}
];

let arrB = [
    {"add_date": "2019-01-22 01:35:25"},
    {"add_date": "2019-08-02 20:24:57"},
    {"add_date": "2019-10-04 14:48:55"}
]

// Merge and sort with newest date first
let arrC = [...arrA, ...arrB].sort((a, b) => a.add_date < b.add_date?  1 :
                                             a.add_date > b.add_date? -1 : 0);

console.log(arrC);
```

Note that this does not copy the objects, the elements of *arrC* are references to the same objects that are in *arrA* and *arrB*.

If you want to convert a string like "2019-06-25 20:39:44" to a Date, do not use the built–in parser. Use a simple parse function or a library as it's not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent and at least one common browser will return an invalid Date.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the date format into timeStamp.then do sorting

Comment: "2019-10-10 18:13:17" **is** a timestamp.